# Does JSHint support async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jshint

I'm using JSHint for the JavaScript project (with the Visual Studio Code). And in this project I use async / await, which JSHint highlights as errors.

I tried to set up jshint, but the it seems like the maxim version of "esversion" is 6.

Does jshint support async/await yet? If it does, how to turn it on? And if not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Probably just use ESLint!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> **Update  (February 2019)** : Async/await are now supported as of version 2.10.1. Simply update your .jshintrc to use `"esversion": 9`. (+Info : [Version changelog](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md))

---

> **Update  (july 2018)** : Async/await will arrive with the release of JsHint 2.10.0. +info : https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/3273

---

The JSHINT developing community considers that:

> - JSHINT should first support all the ES6 syntax before start implementing ES7 features.
> - Async Functions are only at stage 1, so the syntax can change a lot

---

### JSHINT-ESNEXT (PACKAGE)

However, there is an **unnoficial JSHINT package**, wich contains *experimental support for await/async*, called **JSHINT-ESNEXT**.

The author, @[marcominetti](https://github.com/marcominetti), used the official JSHint 2.7 Master branch and introduced this ES7 feature, taken from the [Seb Vincent esnextnext](https://github.com/sebv/jshint/tree/esnextnext) branch.

Check the [Npm Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-esnext), and the [source in github](https://github.com/marcominetti/jshint)

> **Installation**: $npm install -g jshint-esnext

Right now (Jul 2017) this is the only decent available approach to support await/async in JSHINT.

---

### JSHINT IGNORE (DIRECTIVE)

A common suggested workaround or mitigation practice, is using the JSHINT ignore directives.

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Or:

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

I personally find this mitigation practice, dirty and confusing, when our code has a big amount of async/await references. But more confusing and dirty are the JSHINT warnings and errors ;)

Comment: Thanks Colix, this helped. But what about now (Apr, 2018)? Is Async supported in jshint?

Comment: How do you actually use jshint-esnext? Once it's installed, should you be able to use it like `jshint-esnext myscript.js`? Cause that's not working for me.

Comment: To use last features of JS I recommend to use eslint instead of jshint.

Comment: If you get this error: "Incompatible values for the 'esversion' and 'esnext' linting options"
Its due to esnext being deprecated. So remove esnext from your jshint file, and you'll be good. Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-jshint/issues/49

Answer (score 14):

> Does jshint support async/await yet?

No, not yet as of early 2017.

It appears that it does not yet support `async/await`.  Folks working on jsHint have decided not to support `async/await` until standards were in a late stage (having apparently been burned previously by supporting things too early when they were still changing) - though implementations already exist (Babel, nodejs, etc...).

If you follow this [jsHint open issue thread](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2601), it is still an open issue as of recent comments 7 and 11 days ago.

> And if not, are there any workarounds?

As of July 2017, there appears to be a fork of the jsHint code called jshint-esnext that has support for async/await here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-esnext.

Answer (score 4):

Note: Using the forked JSHINT-ESNEXT package ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-esnext), and [github](https://github.com/marcominetti/jshint)) as suggested in the "accepted answer" requires the inclusion of the "experimental" option to be set.

`/* experimental: [asyncawait] */`

or

`/* experimental: [asyncawait, asyncreqawait] */`

See the source code [here](https://github.com/marcominetti/jshint/blob/4391b5f0b7a12d59225aad05ed7f61ad87b459c9/src/options.js#L918) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked it there were any workarounds.  It's a kludge, but I've replaced all my 'async' or 'await' with 'async /**/' and 'await /**/'.  Then a quick script to swap them into '/*async*/' and '/*await*/' allows me to check with jshint.

It's not pretty, but it feeds the bulldog.