# JSHint does not recognise Async/Await syntax in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

I've been struggling with VSCode and JSHint to find out a way to get rid of this syntax highlighting. It seems like JSHint is not able to recognise Async/Await syntax.

Here you can find a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

[image]

My JSHint version: `jshint-esnext v2.7.0-3`

Comment: try to use `eslint`

Comment: @DavidR tsconfig.json is irrelevant here.

Comment: I don't have any `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @chenkehxx What is the point with `eslint` in comparison with `JSHint`?

Comment: ESLint specifically supports most of the new ES features. It can be a bit slower, but it provides (imo) better feedback. It also supports JSX if you're into that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JSHint support the node 7 (async/await)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637630/does-jshint-support-the-node-7-async-await) -- I believe that thread answers the question, which, incidentally, has not much to do with visual studio editor, afaics

Comment: I'm also trying to get jshint-esnext to work with visual studio code.  When I install jshint-esnext, visual studio does not find or use it.  It is apparently only looking for the regular jshint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and this worked for me.  Try using **npm uninstall -g jshint** to completely unistall jshint, then **npm install -g jshint** to re-install the latest version.  Make sure your **package.json** has the following information in it:

"jshintConfig": {
    "esversion": 8,
    "strict": "implied",
    "devel": true,
    "node": true,
    "globals": {}
  }

Answer (score 26):

In visual studio code, JSHint and ESLint cancels each other out. so if you want to use async functions in vscode then you have to disable Jshint and enable eslint instead.