# Error Gulp Build: async functions is only available in es8 (use esversion 8)

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, gulp, ecmascript-2017

When I'm going to compile my code with gulp
displays the following error (image highlighted).
[image: Link to open the print]

It follows the function of the 1685 line that uses async in angular cli.

```
$scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou = async function(chave_indicacao){
        
        chave = {};
        chave.chave_indicacao = chave_indicacao;
        PacienteIndicou = {};
        //console.log('teste getnomepaciente: ', chave);
        return AgendaService.GetNomePacienteIndicou(chave)
            .then(function(data){
                return data.data.dados[0];
                // $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou = data.data.dados[0];
                // this.PacienteIndicou = $scope.GetNomePacienteIndicou; 
                // return this.PacienteIndicou;
            });
          
    };
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JSHint support async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637630/does-jshint-support-async-await)